# convert string to double gives nil

Tags: swift, string, casting, double

I'm parsing a text file to get the latitude and longitude of locations. I need to convert the lon/lat strings to doubles, but I can't do it.

I've tried both the Double(String) method and the (String as NSNumber).doubleValue. It always gives nil.

When I type in the numbers manually it works.

Here's the code snippet:

```
var items = [[String]]()
    func readParkingData() {
        guard let filepath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "parking", ofType: "txt") else {
            print("file not found")
            return
        }
        print("file path : \(filepath)")

        do{
            let content = try String(contentsOfFile: filepath, encoding: .utf8)
            let attributed = content.htmlAttributedString
            let decoded : String = attributed!.string
            let split = decoded.split(separator: ";")

            var count = 0
            var item = [String]()
            for word in split {
                item.append(String(word))
                count += 1
                if count == 30 {
                    items.append(item)
                    item = [String]()
                    count = 0
                }
            }

            for entry in items {
                print(entry[24])
                print(entry[25])
                let latString : String = entry[24]
                let lonString : String = entry[25]
                print(type(of: latString))
                let lat = Double(latString)
                print(lat)

            }

        }catch{
          print("file read error \(filepath)")
        }

    }
```

I've looked through the other answers. The type of latString is String, not optional. Trimming white spaces didn't help either. lat is always nil.

What's going on here?

Comment: Show the output of `print(latString.debugDescription)`

Comment: latString.debugDescription shows "\"40.426687899755734\""

Comment: There is your answer: The number is enclosed in quotation marks. – Btw, why do you operate  on the attributed string instead of the original content? What is the input file format?

Comment: Ah of course. Thanks for that! This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the floating point numbers are enclosed in quotation marks,
so you'll need not only trim whitespace but also quotation marks. Example:

```
let latString = "\"12.34\""
print(latString) // "12.34"

var cs = CharacterSet.whitespaces
cs.insert("\"")

let trimmedLatString = latString.trimmingCharacters(in: cs)
print(trimmedLatString) // 12.34

print(Double(trimmedLatString)!) // 12.34
```

*Further remarks:*

- I do not see the reason to operate on the `htmlAttributedString`, you 
  probably should split the original `content` into lines and fields.
- Is your input a CSV-formatted file? There are open source CSV reader libraries
  which you might try.